# how to conditionally update data field with axios

Tags: react-native, axios, response

i have screen when user have buttons to change hes Name, or phone

i have function that handle if the user clicked on change name or phone

now i want to conditionally implement a **PUT** req, that change only the field that the user clicked,
for example look what exactly i want to do: (look at the **if**)
how can i do that conditinally field?

```
const updateUser = dispatch => async (userId, param, value, token) => {
dispatch({ type: "loading", payload: true });

try {
    const res = await indexApi.put(
        `/user/${userId}`,
        {
        if(param==="name")  name: value,///////////////here
        if(param==="phone")phone: value ////////////here
        },
        {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        }
    );
```

**note** that i also tried to do :

```
name: (param===name) ? value: res.data.user.name
phone: (param===phone) ? value: res.data.user.phone
```

I mean take the data from the server , but the server does not return me and sends me an UNDEFINED comment res.data.user.name undefined................
probably its not enough to get it until the func finish or something

Comment: Did you try to console without if statement for just one parameter ? is the response correct as you expected?

Comment: but i dont know if the user clicked on name or phone, so i need dynamically to know it

Comment: for just confirming pass default as any one them then see is there any problem in response?

Comment: password confirm is not neccesry here, the question is how to conditonaly  send only the name or only phone

Answer (score 2):

if you want to do object with specified `property name` try this:

```
{
  [param]: value
}
```

In brackets value of variable `param` become `'name'` or `'phone'` in your case.

```
const updateUser = dispatch => async (userId, param, value, token) => {
dispatch({ type: "loading", payload: true });

    try {
        const res = await indexApi.put(
            `/user/${userId}`,
            {
             [param]: value
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
            }
        );
```

Comment: And how i declare the param? With string? Const param="name" for example?

Comment: yes, variable value will be parameter name